# SharePoint Error For Reports - File Not Found. at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, reporting, service, report

Experiencing a strange sharepoint error surrounding reports (moss 2007).

Recently we moved to a new development domain and rebuilt our sharepoint servers (with reporting services on the SP frontend).

Everything is fine apart from reports (which do exist), we get the following error when accessing them...

```
File Not Found.   
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, SPUserToken userToken) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl) 
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.RSViewerPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

If I access them from sharepoint on the server itself, the report viewer works fine.

The only thing different to this install over any successful ones in the past is the domain itself.

We need to specify the full domain such as http://sharepoint.dev

Where in the past we've only needed http://sharepoint

With it working on the server, where we dont need to use the full domain only http://sharepoint, this suggests the fully qualified domain .dev could be the issue?

Does anyone have any ideas? Or how to get around this?

Cheers!

Comment: did you built fresh copy or restored it using image of previous environment

Comment: it was a fresh copy of sharepoint with a restore ontop using stsadm. same as we've always done in the past and its worked - it seems simply needing to use a fully qualified domain outside of the server causes the problems

Answer (score 0):

RSViewerPage.OnInit sounds like something hasn't been installed. Have the report viewer controls been installed?

2005

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=8a166cac-758d-45c8-b637-dd7726e61367&displaylang=en

2008

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=CC96C246-61E5-4D9E-BB5F-416D75A1B9EF&displaylang=en

Comment: Already installed. When I'm on the server and run the reports from the reports dir i.e. http://sharepoint/reps/ and access the RDL's from here, the report viewer works fine. But if (again from the server) i change the URL to fully qualified i.e. http://sharepoint.dev/reps then the reports still return the file not found error.